# How to determine what foreign keys are defined in HSQLDB?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, hsqldb

How can I tell what foreign keys have been defined in HSQLDB?

The best I've gleened from the documentation is:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

But that only gave me the following.

```
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA CONSTRAINT_NAME UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME MATCH_OPTION UPDATE_RULE DELETE_RULE 
------------------ ----------------- --------------- ------------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- 
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10078    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10029           NONE         NO ACTION   CASCADE     
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10079    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10029           NONE         NO ACTION   NO ACTION   
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10080    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10071           NONE         NO ACTION   CASCADE     
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10116    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10071           NONE         NO ACTION   CASCADE     
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10120    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10029           NONE         NO ACTION   CASCADE     
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10124    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10029           NONE         NO ACTION   NO ACTION   
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10128    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10071           NONE         NO ACTION   CASCADE     
PUBLIC             PUBLIC            SYS_FK_10131    PUBLIC                    PUBLIC                   SYS_PK_10071           NONE         NO ACTION   CASCADE
```

I need to know what tables and columns have foreign keys assigned, and I need to be able to delete them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following selects in conjunction with the REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS view:

```
select * from information_schema.constraint_column_usage
select * from information_schema.constraint_table_usage
```

Alternatively, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_CROSSREFERENCE view is a self contained view of foreign keys, their tables and columns.

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_information_schema for a list.